# Select one element, with preference for an order of id's

Tags: xpath, xslt

Taken the following example XML. I would like to select the `elm` in preference of the order of the following id sequence: `1, 3, 2`.

```xml
<my:elmList>
    <elms>
        <elm>
            <id>3</id>
        </elm>
        <elm>
            <id>1</id>
        </elm>
        <elm>
            <id>2</id>
        </elm>
    </elms>
    <elms>
        <elm>
            <id>2</id>
        </elm>
        <elm>
            <id>3</id>
        </elm>
    </elms>
</my:elmList>
```

The resulting output should be `1` and `3`, respectively to the `elms` element. Let me emphasize that I can't use `[min(./id)]` since I need `1` in preference of `2` and `3`, but need `3` in preference of `2`.

Comment: Please edit your question and (1) add the **exact** output you expect to get and (2) state which version of XSLT your processor supports (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153).

Comment: Which version of XSLT/XPath? In XSLT/XPath 3 you can select e.g. `//elms!(elm[@id = 1], elem[@id = 3], elm[@id = 2])[1]`

Comment: (3) Make your input XML well-formed by including the namespace declaration.

Comment: As so often happens, we need to know how much the input can vary from the reference example: will the IDs always be numeric, will they always be single digits, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An XPath 2.0 solution that works for any set of IDs (not just single digits) would be

```
(for $id in ("1", "3", "2") return elm[@id=$id])[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that would work even in XSLT 1.0 is to sort the `elm` elements using:

```
<xsl:sort select="translate(id, '23', '32')"/>
```

and then output the first one.

Comment: But this only works, of course, for single-digit IDs.